# Different row count while creating a table or view in Impala

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, impala, hue

Different row count when trying to create a table and view in Impala

I am trying to run a query in Impala having a left outer join with another table. The table structure is as below:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM (
SELECT A.*,
    B.ORDERED_DATE,
    B.PROMISE_DATE,
    B.REQUEST_DATE,
    B.SCHEDULE_SHIP_DATE,
    A.SCHEDULED_START_DATE,
    A.SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE,
               A.DATE_RELEASED,
               A.DATE_COMPLETED,
               B.ORDERED_DATE_DT,
               B.PROMISE_DATE_DT,
               B.REQUEST_DATE_DT,
               B.ORDERED_QUANTITY,
               a.DEMAND_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER,
               B.FLOW_STATUS_CODE,
               A.ORDER_NUMBER
          FROM TABLE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE B
ON (A.DEMAND_SOURCE_LINE_ID) = (B.LINE_ID)
) AAAAA
```

Demand_source_line_id can be null here.

The row count is always different if I do select count(*), count(1). Also the inner select gives me row count different than outer one. Also if i try to create a view out of this query, the record count is different from if i create table out of same query.

Can someone help me?

Expected should be 3585 records. I am getting only 299 on count(*), and 662 on count(1) -- demand source line id is not null for 662 records.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Demand_source_line_id can be null and you are using in on condition, So definitely you will not get expected output and it will impact count as well. 
Can you use coalesce function in on condition e.g coalesce(A.DEMAND_SOURCE_LINE_ID,-1) = coalesce(B.LINE_ID, -1).